# Why i can't redirect browser to index.php page if 'id' not existed?

Tags: php

I'm trying to redirect the query with not existing ID to main page but always get errors caused by entries like

```
"<?php echo $row['script']; ?>"
```

if i did't even check for '$result': 
"Undefined variable: row in C:\www\sts3\page.php on line 37..."

```
require_once("php/db_connect.php"); 
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
  if( $_GET['id'] == '' || !is_numeric($_GET['id']) )  {
    $id = 1;
  }
  else {
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET['id']);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE ID = '" . $id . "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if (empty($result)) {
      header("Location:index.php"); // NOT WORKING HERE
      die();
    }
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$result` is not `empty` if it executed successfully, you need to get the # of rows from the $result to determine if you found your result:

```
if (mysqli_num_result($result) > 0) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}
```

You should also validate/filter your input.

PHP provides a minimal set of validation/filter functions: [PHP Filter functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php)

In your case, you should filter for an `INT`:

```
$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
if (!$id) { // Validation fails. It is recommended you return an error to your user, but in this case I'm going to follow your logic.
    $id = 1;
}
// Do your database queries from here...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is likely that you're using `empty($result))` when `$result` shouldn't be empty, even if the query returns nothing. Instead, try using [`mysqli_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php):

```
require_once("php/db_connect.php"); 
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
  if( $_GET['id'] == '' || !is_numeric($_GET['id']) )  {
    $id = 1;
  }
  else {
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET['id']);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE ID = '" . $id . "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      header("Location:index.php"); // NOT WORKING HERE
      die();
    }
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$row is defined in the "if(isset($_GET['id']))"-block and I guess as soon as you leave this if-block it will be unset as it is not defined before.

In one of the newer versions of php you can't check an array index with isset( ) you better use array array_key_exists( ).